# Magrittr forward pipe fails to forward values into openXL::addWorksheet - "Error ...: First argument must be a Workbook"

Tags: r, tidyverse, magrittr

**`magrittr` appears to be failing to pipe 'workbook' class objects into the `addWorkbook` function from the package `openxlsx`.**

(*Never mind why I need to use excel...eugh yuk*)

For example, to write the `InsectSprays` dataset to an excel file in 'base' syntax:

```
library("openxlsx")
insect.wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb = insect.wb,
             sheetName = "Insect Spray")
writeData(wb = insect.wb,
          sheet = "Insect Spray",
          x= InsectSprays)

openXL(insect.wb)
```

Opens a temp excel file with the data.

So `magrittr` should

> [pipe a value forward into an expression or function call; something
>   along the lines of `x %>% f`, rather than `f(x)`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html)

But e.g.

```
library("openxlsx")
library("magrittr")
insect.wb <- createWorkbook()
insect.wb %>%
  addWorksheet(sheetName = "Insect Spray") %>%
  writeData(sheet = "Insect Spray",
            x= InsectSprays)
```

Returns

> ```
> Error in writeData(., sheet = "Insect Spray", x = InsectSprays) :
> First argument must be a Workbook.
> ```

But `insect.wb` is a workbook object:

```
 > insect.wb <- createWorkbook()
 > class(insect.wb)

[1] "Workbook"
attr(,"package")
[1] "openxlsx"
```

Which suggests that the issue is that the object isn't getting piped in...

**Am I just buggering up the syntax, or is there a more interesting explanation for why this is failing?**

For interest, there is no issue with forward pipe and `writeData` –- if we shift the use of forward-pipes until after `addWorksheet`, it also works fine:

```
insect.wb <- createWorkbook() 
addWorksheet(wb = insect.wb,
             sheetName = "Insect Spray")

insect.wb %>%
  writeData(sheet = "Insect Spray",
            x= InsectSprays)

openXL(insect.wb)
```

Comment: I think `addWorksheet` doesn't return a workbook, and that's the output of `addWorksheet` that you're passing to `writeData`

Comment: It seems to be the case, addWorksheet probably returns TRUE or something like that (doc doesn't say it), it modifies the object directly. Can you try this ? `insect.wb %T>%
  addWorksheet(sheetName = "Insect Spray") %>%
  writeData(sheet = "Insect Spray",
            x= InsectSprays)` (notice the `%T>%` operator). If it works will depend if a copy of insect.wb is made from the start by magrittr or not.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper got it - that works well. I had a poke in the docs but also couldn't tell. If you care to add that as an answer I'll accept

Comment: Hmm yeah `xxx <- addWorksheet(wb = insect.wb, sheetName = "qqq")` returns an integer which seems to be the number of sheets in the workbook. Weird.

Comment: great :), I'm actually surprised that it worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your command chain, writeData takes as a first input the output of `insect.wb %>% addWorksheet(sheetName = "Insect Spray")`

addWorksheet modifies directly the object, and doesn't return the object, so whatever you're passing to writeData is NOT a worksheet (from your comment, it's probably the number of sheets after the add).

You may use the operator `%T>%` and write

```
insect.wb %T>%
  addWorksheet(sheetName = "Insect Spray") %>%
  writeData(sheet = "Insect Spray", x= InsectSprays)
```

`%T>%`starts a new chain in the sense that the ouput of the rhs is not returned, but the lhs is returned, so then writeData takes it where `%T>%` left, except that `insect.wb` has now been modified by `addWorksheet`.