# How to export an Excel file in R?

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 8 worksheets. Each worksheet has a different data and I have a `R` code to update them.

My question is: Is there a way to export a `.xlsx` file in `R` to update only one specific worksheet in my Excel file without replacing the entire spreadsheet for a new file?

In my previous attempts, with the `openxlsx` package, I just created a whole new file, which doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem using the code below.

```
library(migrittr)
library(openxlsx)    

file_path = '/home/user/Downloads/my_sheet.xlsx'

df <- data.frame()

file_path %>%     

          loadWorkbook() %T>%
    
          removeWorksheet(sheet = "Sheet1") %T>%
 
          addWorksheet(sheetName = "Sheet1") %T>%
 
          writeData(sheet = "Sheet1", x = df) %T>%

          saveWorkbook(., file = '/home/user/Downloads/my_sheet.xlsx', overwrite = T)
```

Comment: Why did you use ```%T>%``` instead of ```%>%```?

Comment: This toppic explain well the use of "T" in "%T>%" -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879322/magrittr-forward-pipe-fails-to-forward-values-into-openxladdworksheet-error

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it using the following workflow:

```
# load environment
library(xlsx)
# define file path
file_path = '/home/user/Downloads/my_sheet.xlsx'
# load file as a workbook
file = loadWorkbook(file_path)
# check the sheets in the file
tbls = getSheets(file)
# remove the sheet you want to change
removeSheet(file, sheetName = "Sheet1")
# start a new from scratch
new_sheet = createSheet(file, sheetName = "Sheet1")
# create a dataframe
df = data.frame()
# link the dataframe to the new sheet
addDataFrame(df, new_sheet, row.names = FALSE)
# save the workbook/file
saveWorkbook(file, file_path)
```

Instead of creating a new dataframe from scratch, you can import an old sheet as a dataframe, with `read.xlsx(file, sheetIndex, sheetName)`.

Attention: an error is thrown if you use short file paths, such as `'~/Downloads/my_sheet.xlsx'`.

Comment: Which package is the function ```getSheets```?

Comment: i edited my answer and added `library(xlsx)`. all the functions are built in **xlsx** package. check it out and let me know if it works for you!